# Centering EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to display a label if no data is found in the database:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="no_projects" runat="server" style="color: #ff0000;" Text="[NO PROJECTS FOUND - PLEASE ADD PROJECT DETAILS]" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

The label appears on the left side. I've tried a few different methods, but cannot seem to align it in the center. Thanks for your help!

Comment: EmotyDataTemplate of what? GridView or some other webcontrol?

Answer (score 3):

Use EmptyDataRowStyle:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>     
            <asp:Label ID="no_projects" runat="server" style="color: #ff0000;" Text="[NO PROJECTS FOUND - PLEASE ADD PROJECT DETAILS]" /> 
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
<EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the template a width. Your label is probably showing in its default position, and the grid is full width of the browser.